# Recursively copy apache openmeetings within red5 folder on linux

Tags: apache-httpd, red5-server

I just installed openmeetings for first time on centos 6.5 and it was working but couldn't figure out why
it had a folder full of identical files to my /usr/local/red5 I mean I just can't understand why openmeetings
couldn't just be downloaded in the red5/webapps folder but I've tried and it cannot.

As it stands it wants to start its own red5 server session and redirect to mysite:5080/openmeetings 
but i was hoping it would just share along with other red5 apps and which ever one was open
used the server.  I ended up having to killall java before i could shut down and then restart to open
an app in red5/oflaDemo

You should be able to copy it over but I'm not sure how without making a terrible mess. The apache program compiles itself with red5 scripts attached including its own webapps folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to approach this. I found this PDF with directions on how to build/install OpenMeeting. The document is titled: [][OpenMeetings 2.X Installation on Ubuntu 64bit 12.10][1](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/27838216/Installing%20OM2.x%20On%20Ubuntu64%20-%20Headless%20-%2012.10.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1362051106000&api=v2). These directions can be loosely followed for other distros as well.

If you skip to this section, titled: "[Step 9a: Install pre-built OM 2.x (Alternative to Step 9)](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/download/attachments/27838216/Installing%20OM2.x%20On%20Ubuntu64%20-%20Headless%20-%2012.10.pdf?version=1&modificationDate=1362051106000&api=v2)" there details for getting a prebuilt package of OpenMeeting via the [project's automated build system](https://builds.apache.org/job/openmeetings/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/singlewebapp/dist/).

Looking through that directory structure there are a couple of directories that you'd need to tease out, the `webapps`, `lib`, and `conf` are the 3 that you'll definitely need to separate OpenMeeting out.

You should be able to lift the contents of `webapps` and mix that with your preexisting red5 installation. You'll need to do the same with the `lib` and the `conf` contents as well.

This activity doesn't look to have any simple mechanism for doing this, it's just brute force work in teasing this all apart, but looks fairly doable and straightforward. I was able to find these directions which show the installation method, titled: [Howto install OpenMeetings 2.2 server on a Debian Wheezy box](http://beeznest.wordpress.com/2013/12/30/howto-install-openmeetings-2-2-debian-wheezy/).

Comment: teasing out is the perfect term to use here. I will persist and see if the above links can make more sense of it to me. Get back to this and let you know. Thanks as always.

Comment: I've supported Java applications such as this for 10+ yrs, that's our technical term for this type of work 8-)

Comment: Oh well I appreciate your help, I am currently lost in drupal hell and have to get back to this :)

Comment: I've decided to just leave it as red5/webapps/openmeetings/webapps/openmeetings because it is working fine and because that way I will be forced to remember to start a fresh session of red5 for that program as I can't run both anyway :)